# Android GPS Scatter points when entering a building

Tags: java, android, gps, scatter

I am busy implementing a tracking app where the app tracks you where you go and plot your path on google maps. But when I test it and entered a building I get scatter coordinates.

I know it is because the GPS network is not available inside the building and it switch over to the phone's networking and therefore it gets the scatter coordinates. I have used Kalman Filter to make the points more smooth.

How can you prevent the coordinates to be scattered?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the building the Location attribute "horicontal accuracy estimate" (or similar called) will get much higher.

As a first approach ignore location with have a horAcc higher than 30m.
Additionally you may ignore all locations that are not delivered by GPS_PROVIDER.